# Keras Flatten and GRU input_shape difference receiving same inputs

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I'm looking at an example from a book. The input is of shape (samples=128, timesteps=24, features=13). When defining two different networks both receiving the same input they have different input_shape on flatten and GRU layers.

model 1:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(layers.Flatten(input_shape=(24, 13)))
model.add(layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1))
```

model 2:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(layers.GRU(32, input_shape=(None, 13)))
model.add(layers.Dense(1))
```

I understand that input_shape represents the shape of a single input (not considering batch size), so on my understanding the input_shape on both cases should be (24, 13).

Why are the input_shapes differents between model 1 and model 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GRU is a recurrent unit (RNN), which takes a sequence of data as input. The expected input shape for GRU is (batch size, sequence length, feature size). In your case the sequence length is 24 and feature size is 13.

As usual, you don't need to specify a batch size for input_shape argument. Additionally, for recurrent units like GRU or LSTM you can use "None" instead of sequence length, so that it can accept sequences of any length. This is why "input_shape=(None, 13)" is allowed here.